# Как в Windows 10 с помощью Caps Lock переключать раскладку клавиатуры?

Tags: windows-10

Как в Windows 10 настроить переключение раскладки языка с помощью Caps Lock? Не думал, что в ультра современном и продвинутым Microsoft, простейшая настройка может обернуться такими сложностями.

Answer (score 1):

Поставь [Punto Switcher](https://yandex.ru/soft/punto/win/) - там есть такая настройка. Только не забудь автопереключение выключить и запуск от администратора отметить (а то в программах от админа работать не будет). Ну и остальные опции по желанию расставить.

[image: скриншот настроек]

Comment: а штатными средствами мелкомягких сие сделать ни как? Не сильно хочется ещё одно следящее проприетарное ПО устанавливать.

Comment: @Salanger, не знаю, я Caps Lock не пользуюсь.

Comment: штатными средствами нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Есть статья 2011 года "Переключение языка ввода по caps lock в Windows". Там много вариантов решения. $ https://dae.me/blog/1173/pereklyucheniye-yazika-vvoda-po-caps-lock-v-windows/$

Раньше я использовал Punto Switcher, но иногда не хватало БОЛЬШИХ БУКВ КАПСА. А там Caps был просто занят переключением языка и нельзя было задать функцию капса на какое-нибудь сочетание клавиш типо Caps+Shift. + Яндекс давно уже филиал ФСБ. Я стараюсь постепенно сокращать такие небезопасные практики.

Перешёл на key-manager, но триал закончился, была какая-то проблема с оплатой. Перешёл на Switchy, но у него обнаружились некоторые маленькие раздражающие баги. Пока использую Switchy. Вцелом в 90% случаев он хорошо работает. Но параллельно я снова в поисках идеала. Пока что ничего лучше Switchy я не нашёл. Если найду или сам сделаю, обновлю ответ.

Стоит ещё заметить, в интернете вцелом можно набрать штук 20 таких программок. Но многие из них устарели, другие странно себя ведут (Recaps лепит полупрозрачный значок флага выбранного языка в центр экрана, а при зажатом капсе просто быстро переключает языки - просто безумие а не приложение), какие-то заброшены не дойдя даже до версии 1.0. Забавно, сколько проблем с такой простой функцией. Особенно если хочется просто нормальной работы без сбоев и странных решений разраба.

- Switchy
- Keyla
- LSwitch
- ReCaps
- KbdFlip
- Capslang
- Caps Lock Switch (известная как capsswitch).
- Punto Switcher
- AutoHotkey (позволяет писать скрипты автоматизации и перенастройки клавиатуры)
- Также это можно делать средствами самой системы, если покрасноглазить с реестром Windows.

Comment: было бы неплохо хотя бы вкратце изложить написанное по приведенной ссылке.